# Complications with External Hard Drive after using partitioning Tool

Tags: windows-7, usb, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have ran into a snag with my external hard drive. Last night I was attempting to shink my 1TB hard drive into a 400GB and a 600GB partition (approx). I was using: MiniTool partition Wizzard Home eddition. After hitting apply/perform operation on the hard drive. This failed with an error message which I cannot recall.. It gave me the option to cancel the operation.. So I did, now... My External Hard drive is not showing up in My Computer (Named computer).. Nor in Disk management. I have attempted to re-scan disks in the tool also scanning for Hardware changed under Device manager.

I can confirm that there are no clashing Drive names also.. I have tried numerous restarts and even changing the USB Port which this hard drive is plugged into.. Nothing that I have attempted is working?

So my overall question, is that how else should I approach this problem in order to regain access to my hard drive?

Comment: Its difficult to solve a problem without knowing what the error message was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the manufacturers disk management program IE Seatools, discwizard etc or try Hirens disk.

[DiscWizard](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/discwizard/)

[Hirens Boot CD](http://www.proyectobyte.com/hirens-boot-2/hirens-boot-cd-15-2-usb-2014-everything-one-cd?lang=en)